# How do I only select recipes that I have the ingredients for?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I'm executing the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  r.Recipe_Name
FROM
  USER u
INNER JOIN
  UserIngredient ui
ON
  u.User_ID = ui.User_ID
INNER JOIN
  RecipeIngredient ri
ON
  ui.Ingredient_ID = ri.Ingredient_ID
INNER JOIN
  Ingredient i
ON
  ri.Ingredient_ID = i.Ingredient_ID
INNER JOIN
  Recipe r
ON
  ri.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID
WHERE
  u.User_Session = SessionID
```

and get every recipe that I have at least one ingredient for and not just the recipes that I have ALL ingredients for. My table-layout is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    User_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    User_Pass TEXT NOT NULL,
    User_Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    User_Surname TEXT NOT NULL,
    User_EMail VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    User_Session VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    User_Admin BOOLEAN,
    User_Newsletter BOOLEAN
);
CREATE TABLE Recipe
(
    Recipe_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Recipe_Name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Recipe_Clicks INT,
    Recipe_Description TEXT,
    Recipe_Image VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://placehold.it/400x500'
);
CREATE TABLE Ingredient
(
    Ingredient_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Ingredient_Name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    Ingredient_Description TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE RecipeIngredient
(
    RecipeIngredient_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RecipeIngredient_Amount DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    MeasuringUnit_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Recipe_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Ingredient_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (MeasuringUnit_ID) REFERENCES MeasuringUnit(MeasuringUnit_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Recipe_ID) REFERENCES Recipe(Recipe_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Ingredient_ID) REFERENCES Ingredient(Ingredient_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE UserIngredient
(
    UserIngredient_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Ingredient_ID INT NOT NULL,
    User_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(Ingredient_ID) REFERENCES Ingredient(Ingredient_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(User_ID) REFERENCES User(User_ID)
);
```

The result I get:

I get every recipe that I have one ingredient

The result I want:

All recipes that I have **ALL** ingredients.

[Here](https://github.com/Sven-Niehus/cocktail-database/blob/master/SQL/cocktails.sql) is my SQL file

Comment: Care to share some sample data and some sample output from the query that returns everything

Comment: If your middletable for a recipe is empty you don't want to show that recipe?

Comment: @Matt sure: https://github.com/Sven-Niehus/cocktail-database/blob/master/SQL/cocktails.sql

Comment: @JoeTaras If I don't have all of the ingredient listened in RecipeIngredient in UserIngredient I don't want to show the recipe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Recipe_Name
FROM Recipe r
CROSS JOIN User u
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM RecipeIngredients ri
     LEFT OUTER JOIN UserIngredient ui
     ON ri.Recipe_ID = ui.Recipe_ID
     AND ri.Ingredient_ID = ui.Ingredient_ID
     AND ui.User_ID = u.User_ID
     WHERE ui.UserIngredient_ID IS NULL) = 0
```

Comment: Sorry that it took took me so long to answer, but I had no time to check if this is going to work. Sadly it's not giving me the desired result